# railsでの画像のバイナリデータの取得

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsで画像を選択して保存したいのですが、指定したパスにファイルはできますがバイナリデータの取得がうまくいかないために正しいファイルが作成されません。以下にコードを載せます。

view(画像に関係する部分のみ載せます)

```
<%= form_tag(action: :create, :multipart => true) do %>
  <%= label :book, :画像1 %>
  <%= file_field :book, :image_name1 %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def create
    @book = Book.create(create_params)
    image = params[:book][:image_name1]
    File.open("public/books_image/#{@book.image_name1}", "wb"){
        |f| f.write(image.read)
    }
    if @book.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
end
private
def create_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:name, :isbn, :author, :lesson, :money, :image_name1, :user_id).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

model

```
  t.string :image_name1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
params[:book][:image_name1]
```

はアップロードされたファイルを参照するためのオブジェクトですので、これをデータベースに保存しても意味ありません。パスとしてそのまま使ってもいけません。

ファイルアップロードのやり方以前に、Railsの基礎の部分からいろいろおかしいので、入門書やhttps://railstutorial.jp などで一通りのことを勉強されることをお勧めします。Railsチュートリアルには画像のアップロードについても記載があります。